# Display Mismatched Rows belonging to Same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Student table**

```
Student Id  Student Name
1           Vijay
2           Ram
```

**Student Detail Table**

```
Student ID  Code    StudentIdentityNumber
1          Primary      143
1          Secondary    143
1          Teritary     143
2          Primary      123
2          Secondary    123
2          Teritary     126
```

Output required

```
StudentID  PrimaryIdentity    SecondaryIdentity                 TeritaryIdentity


2          123                             123                            126
```

I just want this output. The output doesnt have StudentID 1 because for him primary secondary and teritary Numbers are same. Hope it is clear

Need simple solution. Yes Code column is Only three. Static only

Comment: Is `Code` column limited to the shown 3 values?

Comment: Yes Code column limited to the 3 values

Comment: Even if you are able to Give generic solution without code limitation, it is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below query:
Hope it helps you.

```
WITH cte 

as (SELECT StudentID , [Primary],[Secondary],[Teritary] 
FROM 

(SELECT 
StudentID , Code, StudentIdentityNumber FROM StudentDetail) s

Pivot

( max(StudentIdentityNumber) for Code in ( [Primary],[Secondary],[Teritary]) )as pvt

)

SELECT * FROM cte where cte.[Primary]<>cte.[Secondary] or cte.[Primary]<> cte.Teritary
```

Comment: How is this different than my answer (other than being noisier)?

Comment: Was not intending to be offensive rather as you can see have  just given another way of querying its not a copy of urs instead have jst used CTE.. Its upto @jamir which one to opt.... if it seems noisier to u apologises for the same.

Comment: @jp_dev  You people are doing good job. But PM 77-1  answer is helping me .However I wil analyze all answers and mark correct answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  The query is good. But ISNULL(cte.[Primary],'')<>ISNULL(cte.[Secondary],'') Will even check null values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sd1.Student, 
       sd1.StudentIdentityNumber as Primary,
       sd2.StudentIdentityNumber as Secondary,
       sd3.StudentIdentityNumber as Teritary
FROM StudentDetail sd1
JOIN StudentDetail sd2
  ON sd1.StudentID  = sd2.StudentID  
 AND sd1.Code = 'Primary'
 AND sd2.Code = 'Secondary'
JOIN StudentDetail sd3
  ON sd2.StudentID  = sd3.StudentID 
 AND sd2.Code = 'Teritary' 
WHERE sd1.Primary <> sd2.Secondary
  or  sd1.Primary <> sd3.Teritary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select pvt.StudentID, 
pvt.[Primary] PrimaryIdentity, 
pvt.Secondary SecondaryIdentity, 
pvt.Teritary TeritaryIdentity
from StudentDetail sd
pivot
(
    max(StudentIdentityNumber)
    for code in ([Primary],Secondary,Teritary)
) as pvt
where pvt.[Primary] <> pvt.Secondary 
or pvt.Secondary <> pvt.Teritary
```

Comment: Cool. Your answer is also correct. I just choosed the best one.